Angular Signal Store not Automatically Updating Ag-Grid ServerSide RowModel Type
I am trying to use the SignalStore combined with the Serverside rowmodel with Ag-Grid. However, even though data is updated in the store, it is not reflected in the Ag-Grid View
Reproducible Link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nv8tjl
This is the current behavior.
Can anyone please suggest to me where I went wrong while implementing?


By using [...response] instead of [...response.rowData], I was able to make it work:
              next: (response) => {
                updateState(store, 'product-users', (state: any) => ({
                  isLoaded: true,
                  data: [...response], // <-- was [...response.rowData]
                  count: response.rowCount,
                }));
              },

Because the mock.data.json did not load (404), I've made some adjustments in your product.service.ts as well.
Link to the working solution:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bzpge2?file=src%2Fproduct%2Fproduct.store.ts

I tried the same as mentioned, but the moment I change the response to delay by 1000/2000ms I am getting the same issue. Here is stack blitz for the same.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rdtez8
